# Web is extremely janky on iOS when in low power mode

Tags: flutter

On iOS when in low power mode (yellow battery) - Flutter web feels terrible.

It janks and the most basic animation of pressing a button looks very bad. There must be some animation resource issue - anyone know how to fix this before I open a new issue? Most of my users are on low power mode by mid day, and it looks like the developer does not know what he is doing.

This is on the most basic app and been an issue for long on all my projects.

On any other platform or normal battery, Flutter performs very well, smooth as butter. I am not new to Flutter, it's amazing - but the issue is valid.